# ***.tmp is not a valid win32 resource file. How to resolve this weird bug on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I use Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

I'm experiencing a boring bug, that sometimes break my compilation processes with something like:

Error   4   'C:\dev(...)\obj\Debug\CSC4B.tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file   (...)

This file doesn't even is shown in the \Debug folder. The only way I can solve this (temporarily) is to restart the machine. It is happening more frequently now.

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

**NOTE:**

I've searched in many places for resolving this bug. Most places mention something with icons, but I have set no icons to projects in this solution.

Comment: I got this when my machine was low on memory. Closing some processes to free up memory resolved it.

Comment: Hi Victor, I am using visual studio 2010 and MVC 3. I am getting below error while building the project 'CSCA37D.tmp is not a valid Win32 resource file'. I tried above mentioned solutions but not getting the resolution. I didn't find any process named GDI++ running on my machine. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was really weird. And the fault was of GDI++, an application that changes the way Windows renders text. After closing this processes, everything is just working fine (except the text rendering).

Comment: "an application that changes the way Windows renders text" What do you mean?

Comment: Me neither got it. And what the name of the precess by the way? I am experiencing the same problem with VS 2010 in my virtualBox. If the «GDI++» just the name, I had never seen it (nor I see it now).

Comment: Hm, I think I found the actual problem: for the time of working Visual Studio creates a bunch of temporary files *(not the ones it complains)*. I've no idea what the files it is because these pretty large. For a day of work its count exceeds 1Gb, and my VitualBox goes out of space. I ignored it since a project is anyway in a shared dir of a GNU/Linux, but now I believe that in the end of a space in a system partition, VS starts suffer of some bug despite large space at the actual location of an object files. To resolve it is needed to close VS — to force it to remove a created temporary files.

Comment: Hi Victor, I am using visual studio 2010 and MVC 3. I am getting below error while building the project 'CSCA37D.tmp is not a valid Win32 resource file'. I tried above mentioned solutions but not getting the resolution. I didn't find any process named GDI++ running on my machine.